# Android: change dynamically ListView item background color

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth

I've a problem with dynamically changing the text color in `ListView`.
I have a `ListView` with names of bluetooth devices and I need to change the background color of the visible devices. I'm running `broadcastReceiver` and when device name equals position in list I'm changing background color. This is my code:

```
devicesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pairedDevicesListView);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.text_view_layout, DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getCounters(false));
    devicesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And `broadcastReceiver`:

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Broadcast Receiver");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        ArrayList<String> devicesInDB = DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getCounters(false);
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            System.out.println(device.getName());
            availableDevices.add(device.getName());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i = 0; i < devicesList.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if(device.getName().equals(devicesInDB.get(i))) {
                    devicesList.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Detecting devices is working correctly,  but the background color looks like it was changed randomly. Can someone help me?

Comment: Since Android reusing views, this approach seems to be iffy. I would suggest passing information to adapter, make some if statement on `getView` method in adapter to change color in particular view and than call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved this problem without overriding getView in Adapter :)